# How to upload an image using Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: symfony

I am working on a project using symfony.I want to use Sonata Media bundle,in order to upload image.
Unfortunately I don't knwo how to use it  or how to start.

I havethis form :

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="filePhotoForm form-inline" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-start-order browse" value="Browse">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control file-name" readonly="readonly" placeholder="No file selected">
                                <input type="file" name="filePhoto" id="filePhoto" class="hidden file-upload">
                            </div><br/><br/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
```

And the code in controller:

```
 public function changePictureAction(Request $request)
    {


        return $this->render('MedAppBundle:Profile:change_picture.html.twig');
    }
```

Can you help with the basics of uploading?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonataMediaBundle - how to upload images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526457/sonatamediabundle-how-to-upload-images)

Comment: Why do you need SonataMediaBundle ? If you just want upload images, look at the Symfony file upload recipes.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html

Answer (score 0):

i have made a custom function for that

```
protected function saveImageMediaBundle($file,$context = 'default')
{

    $mediaManager = $this->get('sonata.media.manager.media');
    $media = new Media();
    $media->setContext($context);
    $media->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
    $media->setBinaryContent($file);
    $mediaManager->save($media);

    return $media;
}
```

and get file by this

```
$file = $request->files->get('newsImage',null);
$media = $this->saveImageMediaBundle($file,'news');
```